# Putting men and women around a table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm wondering how to sit 7 men and 7 women around a table such that no matter what 2 people of opposite gender aren't sitting across each other?
Can I subtract from the whole circle permutation of 14 people the number of permutations when a man and a woman sit across, or I can sit all men as a block, and then sit 7 women after?

Comment: I suggest you count the number of possible pairs man-woman then count the number of ways you can sit the seven pairs around the table.

Comment: Makes sense, so would the solution be: (7-1)! * 2^7, first one would be the order of the pairs, and then the number of permutation in the pairs?

Comment: I have doubts about $2^7$ part. If we have one man and one woman, we have only one pair, not two.

Comment: There are 7 pairs, inside a pair man and woman can switch places, so that's my explanation of that

Comment: The way I look at it, the first man can choose out of 7 women, the second man - out of 6 and so forth.

Comment: What is the source of the problem ?  Also, please quote the **exact** wording of the source.

Comment: If you're looking for the number of arrangements that have *no* male-female pairs sitting across from each other, then it can't be done - there will be 7 pairs of people sitting across from each other, and you can have at most 3 male-male pairs and 3 female-female pairs.